# Why does URL Redirect in Flask work in console but now in the actual web app?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'll try to include only the necessary code to solve my problem -- I am trying to redirect to my home page ('/' - index.html) in another function in Flask, but it does not work in the browser. It shows the correct response in the web Console though (Firefox)

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request, redirect, session, flash
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        # read the user posted values from the UI
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # sql stuff
            if len(data) is 0:
                flash('User account created successfully.')
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        # close sql stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

signUp.js

```
$(function(){

    $('#btnSignUp').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUp',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>wApp</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../static/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/signUp.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li role="presentation" ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/showSignin">Sign In</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">wApp</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>wApp</h1>
        <form class="form-signin" action="/signUp" method="post">
        <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Sign up</button>
      </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've omitted a bunch of stuff, but is there anything glaringly wrong here? The relevant portion is the flash and return redirect('/'). I want to redirect to the main page @ 'index.html' This displays the result in the web Console, but in the web application nothing happens. My html index page has the code for receiving the flash as well.

Comment: Is `signup.html` using a normal form submission or is it using AJAX - all of your responses are using `json.dumps` except for the redirect, which suggests you are using JavaScript and want to redirect if successful, but you aren't dealing with a "full" browser request.

Comment: signup.html is indeed using ajax, i've added the signup.html and signUp.js to my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you submit the singUp form using javascript, you have to redirect the client using javascript as well. The `return redirect('/')` line in the `singUp()` function just redirects the Ajax request, but the client is still on the singup page. Instead of that line you should return a status code: `return json.dumps({'status': 'ok'})` and redirect the client like this:

**signUp.js**

```
$(function(){    
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUp',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                window.location.href = "http://example.com";
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense, so I was redirecting the Ajax but not doing anything for the client. When is the use case for using "redirect" then? Also, is there a way to make the window.location.href agnostic to domain/IP information? For example, right now I have window.location.href = "127.0.0.1:5002", but in the future when my IPs change, I don't want to have 127.0.0.1 hardcoded. Is there a relative way to do this, similar to redirect('/')?

Comment: Flask's `redirect()` useful when you want to redirect the client on the server side. For example during the login process: the client enters its username/password at `/login` and submits the form. You check the data and forwards the client to the main page using `redirect('/')`. You can do the same with javascript, it's up to you which method to prefer.

Answering the second question: yes, you can use relative paths, like `window.location.href = "/"`. Just don't forget to add the base URL if your app is in a subdirectory (e.g. `http://example.net/myapp/ -> /myapp/`).